# Is there a JDBC Driver for Microsoft SSAS Tabular Databases?

Tags: ssas, jdbc

Is there a JDBC Driver for Microsoft SSAS Tabular Databases?  Is so where can they be downloaded?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There used to be a OLAP JDBC driver that supported SSAS called [olap4j](http://www.olap4j.org/) but it has not been updated in a while and I am not sure of its support for anything above 2012. It is always worth a try though.

Communication with an SSAS instance is done using [XMLA](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187178.aspx) , which itself is based upon the SOAP protocol. Technically you should be able to send queries using a standard SOAP client with embedded XMLA statements.

That being said, I know that Microsoft uses a proprietary implementation for their SOAP over TCP/IP so you may need to [tinker](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/ed6d7e90-0ca0-4b4b-8c5a-9e3757100800/can-we-connect-to-analysis-services-using-java?forum=sqlanalysisservices) with your client to get it to work.

Some additional detail is given in FrankPI's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21232057/query-analysis-services-cubes-in-java-without-using-msmdpump-dll) on StackOverflow where somebody asked a similar question and there is even a [suggestion](https://ideas.powerbi.com/forums/282523-bi-in-sql-vnext/suggestions/7146083-native-support-for-java-application-to-analysis-se) open for Power BI that requests interoperability between Java and SSAS.

If none of the above solutions work for you I am afraid you will have to roll your own or use the supported [ADOMD.NET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/analysis-services/multidimensional-models-adomd-net-client/adomd-net-client-programming) components.

Comment: There is also [jdbc4olap](https://sourceforge.net/projects/jdbc4olap/) which seems equally defunct (and so likely doesn't support tabular). i posted as a comment since I wasn't sure you wanted that as an edit to your answer.